# Inbox notification number-badge on top of "StackExchange"

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image: inbox bug]

It's also off-place here in meta.

I'm on Chrome 10.0.648.205 and Mac OS X 10.6.7

Comment: good catch. the fix will be in the next deployment